# Remove "Save draft" button without using CSS

Tags: buttons, draft, customization

Is there a way to remove "Save draft" button without the use of CSS?

Comment: What's wrong with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just remove the "Save draft" as the button is tied up in the `submitdiv` metabox HTML defined in the function `post_submit_meta_box()`.

However we can alter the callback for this metabox and replace it with our own function.

We can bind to the `submitpost_box` event and give the binding a height weight so it fires last...

```
add_action('submitpost_box', 'my_module_edit_form_after_editor', 100);
```

Then when our action is called we can swap out the metabox callback:

```
function my_module_edit_form_after_editor() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    $post_type = 'feed';
    $context   = 'side';
    $priority  = 'core';

    $wp_meta_boxes[$post_type][$context][$priority]['submitdiv']['callback'] = 'my_custom_post_submit_meta_box';

}
```

And then we just need to define what our custom metabox will look like. You could just take the core function `post_submit_meta_box()` and put it into your own plugin removing the unneeded sections, however I would recommend using an actual template and not just closing php tags half way though a function as that just leads to difficult to follow horrible spaghetti code.

Answer (score -2):

Please put the below lines in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 'false');
```